# Ubuntu gnome 15.10 Compizconfig PROBLEM!

Tags: gnome, 15.10, compiz

Hello i am trying to set magic lamp effect for minimizing the windows with compizconfig and it doesnt do it no matter how many times i've tried! Am i doing something wrong or just gnome doesnt support it?

Comment: Does GNOME 3 use Compiz? It uses Mutter instead, so it cannot be configured by Compiz configuration utility.

Answer (score 2):

Gnome does not support such desktop effects. If you are looking for a Linux OS with those desktop effects, go for Kubuntu, it contains the KDE Plasma 5 desktop, and it supports/contains those features you seek.

Comment: I prefer gnome more but i was reflect! ty for answering

Comment: **@Grimmjow** Please don't thank **TheChosenOne99** !  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** at the left of this text right now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the number, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!  **;-)**